# Batch file runs fine but not in Task Scheduler

Tags: batch-file, ssis, scheduled-tasks

Afternoon everyone,

I've tried to research this topic in depth and I cannot come to a conclusion for my problem. I'm trying to automate a batch file in Task Scheduler to execute two SSIS packages. Currently when I attempt to execute the scheduled task (either waiting for its set schedule or running on demand), task scheduler will show that the task has completed successfully, the "Status" will continue to say "Running" but the destination files are never created/re-created. This is the script:

```
dtexec /f "D:\SSIS\Folder\Folder\Folder\Package.dtsx"
dtexec /f "D:\SSIS\Folder\Folder\Folder\Package.dtsx"
```

The SSIS is supposed to pull information from SQL and export it to a CSV which it does wonderfully... If I execute this script in CMD, Powershell, or run my batch file directly.

About my environment:

- My script resides on a SQL Server. (Windows Server 2016 Standard)
- I have a domain admin account used for scripting permissions (all parent folders including the batch file itself have that domain admin added with full permissions, including the csv destination).
- The scheduled task is set to: "Run whether user is logged on or not", "Run with highest privileges", Configured for Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008. I know my credentials are correct for my domain admin account.
- In "Actions", "Program/script:" is currently set to "C:\Scripts\file.bat", there is nothing in "Add Arguments (optional):" currently, "Start in (optional):" is set to "C:\Scripts".

So here is what I've tried:

- I've set "Program/script:" to "cmd.exe" and added an argument of "file.bat" with a start in as "C:\Scripts", no dice.
- I've set "Program/script:" to "Powershell.exe" and set an argument of "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass C:\Scripts\file.bat" with a start in as "C:\Scripts", no luck again.
- I added my domain admin account to the local administrators group on the server as well.
- I've changed the user/group from my domain admin account to my domain admin account (the one I'm logged into the server with) and set it to "Run only when user is logged on", if this is set and I attempt to run the scheduled task, CMD flashes on screen and disappears before I can read anything (it's still too fast for the script to actually run, it takes ~20 seconds) and the destination file isn't altered.
- (This one really stumps me) I've tried to add the script to another scheduled task on the server, that scheduled task will run on schedule and complete every script in the batch file except for these 2 lines. The other scheduled task it was added to uses the same domain admin account, same settings across the board, it even has other similar SSIS packages being run using "dtexec", I don't get it.

Thanks for any input anybody can give me, it's greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is D: a local or network drive?

Comment: Sorry about that, D is a local drive. All file directories are explicit.

Comment: Where is dtexec located?  I would explicitly define the whole path to the executable.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question, but those 2 lines of code are in my batch file. (C:\Scripts\file.bat)

Comment: I don't know much about Task Scheduler, but have you tried using a SQL Server Agent job? Since you are on SQL Server 2016, you can deploy the packages to the SQL Server with Project Deployment and then create a job that runs on a user-defined schedule.

Comment: Dtexec is located in what folder? Use the fully qualified path to the program in your batch file.

Comment: Choose "Run only when user is logged on" option. And in the batch file add a `pause` command at the end of the file. If there is an error CMD will not close and you can see the exception.

Comment: @Squashman, dtexec is located here: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio. Adding the full qualified path did not seem to change anything.

Comment: @Hadi, I changed the option you mentioned, changed the account to the account I'm currently logged in as, and added the pause and got several errors: 0x8007003 (The system cannot find the path specified), the destination csv files are on a separate server. I then get 0xC020200E (Cannot open the datafile "G:\Folder\Folder\file.csv"), and then finally 0xC004701A (Flat File Destination failed the pre-execute phase and returned error code 0xC020200E).

Comment: While investigating these errors, I found that I used a mapped drive in my Flat File Connection Managers (the G: drive in my previous comment), I changed the location to the fully qualified file path. Now my scheduled task performs as expected with either account attached to it. Thanks for the assistance friends!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a super old post, but I just had the same issue and wasn't successful with any other popular solutions around StackOverflow, so I want to put out an alternative solution for anyone still struggling!

When in doubt, double check the user account in the Security Options under Properties (right-click on Task > Properties > first page under "Security Options").

Even though the user that it had selected by default should have permission to execute the script, I had to change the user account to a user with a higher privilege (I'm on a work computer). For me, this meant I had to select the Administrator group on my particular desktop environment.